# How to display entire line that have error in terminal node.js

Tags: node.js, terminal

I saw someone posted this screenshot:

[image]

This is an angular ng serve displaying the part of the file that have got an error, how can I have the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you'll have a try/catch snippet, you can use the following

```
var stack = new Error().stack
console.log( stack ) //will print file and line plus the stack
```

or

```
console.trace()
```

Similarly, node.js does print the error's stack trace by default. You can look at all these
lines until you find a source file that is made by you - it's the old style but it doesn't fail when it comes to finding the exact source of your error. For example

```
Error: Something unexpected has occurred.
at main (c:\Users\Me\Documents\MyApp\app.js:9:15)  //this file would be yours
at Object. (c:\Users\Me\Documents\MyApp\app.js:17:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3
```

I hope this helps

Comment: If reading the stack trace becomes too hard, this library can help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-error